# Get instances from a DLL/Assembly?

Tags: c#, dll

[I already posted something very similar but the question wasn't good, here is what I really wanna know]

I got the following code that generates a DLL :

```
public class MyObject : DependencyObject
{
}


public class Timer : DependencyObject
{
}

public class AnotherClass
{
}

public class Test
{
    MyObject q1 = new MyObject();
    MyObject q2 = new MyObject();
    MyObject q3 = new MyObject();
    MyObject q4 = new MyObject();

    Timer t1 = new Timer();
    Timer t2 = new Timer();
    Timer t3 = new Timer();

    AnotherClass a1 = new AnotherClass();
    AnotherClass a2 = new AnotherClass();
    AnotherClass a3 = new AnotherClass();
    }
}
```

Then I'd like to extract instances from my DLL file. Here is what I got for the moment :

```
var library = Assembly.LoadFrom(libraryPath);
```

But then, I havent any idea about how to extract my 10 instances (4 MyObjects, 3 Timers & 3 AnotherClasses). The only thing I managed to get is the 4 classes (MyObject, Timer, AnotherClass and Test) with the code :

```
IEnumerable<Type> types = library.GetTypes();
```

but I think this is not the way I'll get my 10 instances...

(ps : I'm not even sure that the 10 instances are contained in my DLL file...)

Comment: Can you not just reference your dll in the consuming project, and then use it as you would any other class library?

Comment: Nop, I can as I will dynamicaly load any dll in a specific folder :/

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are doing that, rather than including the dll as part of your project?

Comment: The "10 instances" here are actually "per instance of `Test`, of which there could be **any** number (more than likely: zero), and I know I could create an instance of `Test` **without** any of the child objects (i.e. where `q1` etc are all `null`). There's a lot of assumptions in here that simply don't hold much water.

Comment: " I'm not even sure that the 10 instances are contained in my DLL file" instances, conceptually, only makes sense in memory; the file just contains IL metadata.

Comment: The 'assembly' tag is for low level programming, not for .NET assemblies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot easily get all instances of a given type. That simply doesn't exist, outside of some pretty hardcore debugging APIs (think: SOS). If you need this, you should think of some other, manageable way of tracking your instances (ideally without keeping them alive, so `WeakReference`).

Comment: +1 there are some good frameworks out there for managing external objects ie MEF > http://mef.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate an instance of `Test`.  Those instances won't exist until you do.

Now, I suspect what you *really* want to do is have a singleton (a frowned upon design pattern for a number of reasons).  However, this is what you'd do if you want it:

```
public class Test
{
    private static Test instance_ = new Test();

    MyObject q1 = new MyObject();
    MyObject q2 = new MyObject();
    MyObject q3 = new MyObject();
    MyObject q4 = new MyObject();

    Timer t1 = new Timer();
    Timer t2 = new Timer();
    Timer t3 = new Timer();

    AnotherClass a1 = new AnotherClass();
    AnotherClass a2 = new AnotherClass();
    AnotherClass a3 = new AnotherClass();

    public Test Instance { get { return instance_; } }
}
```

Now, assuming you make those members publically available, you can get at them with:

```
Test.Instance.a1;  // etc...
```

Now, as I've said singletons aren't generally a good idea.  It would be better to instantiate your own instance of Test from your dependent module and work with that.